# How to generate a PHP form for each (unique) redirecting URL?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, url, identity

I'll try to be as brief as possible regarding what I'm trying to accomplish:

- Lets say I'm sending a message via SMS & Email to 5000 contacts (but I wish this to work for even only 10 or 1.000.000, no matter the volume).
  In this message, I'm promoting an event like, say, a dinner party at some fancy place. Everyone who received this message is invited.
  Every message contains an URL, linking to a landing page dedicated to the event. This page is responsive, it opens with a nice pic + some text, basic information and a PHP form to answer the invitation.
- This form has a few fields. In this example, let's say:

  > Are you coming to the party ? (answer to choose from : "Yes" or "No thanks").
  >   Will you be accompanied ? (answer to choose from : "Just me" or "+1", "+2").
  >   Anything else you'd want to let us know ? (free typing field).
  >   [SUBMIT]
- Each URL link in the messages sent are actually UNIQUE redirections, each one belonging to 1 of the 5000 contacts reached.
  Each contact received his own link on both the SMS and the email.
  All of this means that in the database I use to send the messages, each contact has been attributed a redirection/short URL.
  This way, I can very well know who even just opened the landing page, without needing to ask the openers to fill any information.
  I just know that, for example:

  ```
  Mr. Skywalker is http://website.com/dinnerparty/01
  Ms. Organa is http://website.com/dinnerparty/02
  Mr. Solo is http://website.com/dinnerparty/1138
  Mr. Calrissian is http://website.com/dinnerparty/4469

  And they all redirect to http://website.com/dinnerparty/
  ```

So far so good, right ?!
Now here's the tricky part...

- What I need you guys to help me with, is how to "link and lock" the PHP form on the page to these unique URLs.
  Basically, when Mr. Calrissian clicks on /4469, I want him to be able to click "Yes" (I'm coming to the party), "+2", [SUBMIT].

Once he submitted that, if he refreshes the page, he can no longer submit the form. Instead, he sees a message like "Your answer has been received, thank you !"
The page is essentially the same for everyone in the contact list, but as it's HIS link, it's HIS form that shows.

- After that, I need to be able to retrieve these informations (the choices he made).

I know this can be done because I came across this kind of process before. I just don't know how to reproduce it! I'm not a programmer, just a noob trying to learn "by myself".

So far, I think I have to somehow give and ID to each of the 5000 forms and I just guess the information saying 'this URL = this form' is gonna be contained in the URL, that will look something like 'http://website.com/dinnerparty-356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab'

Does all this ring any bell ? My enquiries so far (playing with keywords "PHP" & "URL") just taught me how to transfer informations from a contact form to the content of another page with the GET array, but it's not what I need.

So if you got any clue, any lead regarding how to realize this, I'd be grateful!

Thanks for reading, any help will be much appreciated!

PS: sorry for bad english ;)

Answer (score 0):

First things first, don't use incremental ID's. This is prone to what's known as a sequential number attack. Use UUID's instead. Otherwise, a guest could enter the next/previous/random ID and possibly RSVP for another guest. This is bad news for you, but great for an attacker (they'll be doin' it for the lulz... this could cost the victim big $$$, such as buying unnecessary dinners, for example). See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgJudU_jlZ8 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8 for some good explanations.

Secondly, you should maintain the UUID in the URL, such as `http://website.com/guest/123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000` -- using a script or something like `.htaccess`, you can pickup the UUID and pass it to a single script. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/guest/(.*)$ /my-form.php?id=$1 [L]
```

From there, in your my-form.php, you can check to see if `$_GET['id']` exists, and then validate it (does it exist? Has it previously been submitted? etc). If it validates, you can then display the form as usual and post to self (with the UUID in the url, still). On submit, you validate the ID again, and process the submission.

Then, on subsequent page loads, you can deny the form from being submitted again... or conversely, allow users to EDIT their response. Maybe they'll no longer be a +2... but the use case is up to you, some RSVP's don't allow edits after X date... so keep this in mind.

--

Now, to discuss mass SMS/Email services, you would want to have a database of users already. In order to send unique links, you'd just need to do what's known as a "Mail merge" (or merge tags, etc)... Basically, you would have the URL in the newsletter/message like: `http://website.com/guest/[guest_id]` and the mailmerge would replace `[guest_id]` with the UUID in your database.

There are plenty of mail/sms mass mailing services out there, so I don't need to list any. Pick one that has an API and fits your requirements.

Hope this helps. Good luck :)